# Azure App Service Container Images force pulled from Docker Hub instead of ACR

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-image

Does Azure App Service only support images stored in Docker when defined using the **Docker Compose Preview**.

My images are stored in Azure Container Registry (ACR). Yet when I refer to my image stored in ACR using the Docker compose preview, it trys to pull the images from Docker Hub instead, **registry-1.docker.io**, where they are not stored and fails.

`DockerApiException: Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/dev/my_container/manifests/latest: unauthorized: incorrect username or password"}`

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  container_one:
    image: "dev/container_one"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
  container_two:
    image: "dev/container_two"
    ports:
      - "81:81"
    restart: always
```

[image]

Comment: You have to include the link to your ACR

Comment: In the image tag right? Something like `image: "my.azurecr.io/dev/container_one"` right?

Comment: Yes you need to include the ACR repo name before the actual image otherwise it will default to pulling from Docker Hub - Does it not work when you update the container_one and container_two image references to `image: "my.azurecr.io/dev/container_one"` ?

Comment: Go to your ACR and click your image tag, it will show you the Artifact reference, which you need to set as the value for the image.

Comment: Thanks all, including the full link to ACR fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to include the full link to my ACR. Based on Hong Ooi's comment.

Using `my.azurecr.io/dev/container_one` solved my issue. My full configuration now looks like:

```sh
version: '3.3'
services:
  container_one:
    image: "my.azurecr.io/dev/container_one"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    restart: always
  container_two:
    image: "my.azurecr.io/dev/container_two"
    ports:
      - "81:81"
    restart: always
```

Comment: You saved me. I wasted many hrs to figure out why it was using docker hub